# When scaling out an app service in Azure, is a single message (from the queue) processed on all instances?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I am using an azure web job to pick up messages off the queue and process them as shown below:

```
namespace TicketProcessor
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("ticketprocessorqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            //DO STUFF HERE...
        }
    }
}
```

And this web job exists within an app service in my azure account. My volume has been steadily increasing, and I now need to "scale this out". I need this same web job to run on multiple instances simultaneously. There are 2 reasons for this:

1. More processing power
2. My service targets a web api that throttles according to IP

I see the option within my app service to "Scale Out". But I'm not sure of the internal workings of the message queue as it relates to the scale out. My particular concern is this: **If I scale this app service out to 2 instances, and my web job runs on both (as shown above), will each message in the queue get processed twice (once on each instance)?** Or does the Azure queue mechanism handle it in such a way that each message is processed only once by one of the two instances?

One more thing to consider - in reading up on this, I found that there are two types of queues in Azure (storage queues and service bus queues). One thing I found interesting in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#foundational-capabilities) (in the "Foundational Capabilities" section) is that the Delivery guarantee for storage queues is "At-Least-Once". But the Delivery guarantee for service bus queues is both "At-Least-Once" and "At-Most-Once". This *seems* to indicate that if my process runs in a service bus queue, then it is guaranteed to run only once. But if it runs in a storage queue, it could possibly run more than once. In my case, I am running it with a storage queue. Any clarity on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> If I scale this app service out to 2 instances, and my web job runs on
>   both (as shown above), will each message in the queue get processed
>   twice (once on each instance)?

The answer to your question is no. Each message will be processed only once. From this [`link`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues#trigger) ("Multiple Instances" section):

> If your web app runs on multiple instances, a continuous WebJob runs
>   on each machine, and each machine will wait for triggers and attempt
>   to run functions. The WebJobs SDK queue trigger automatically prevents
>   a function from processing a queue message multiple times; functions
>   do not have to be written to be idempotent. However, if you want to
>   ensure that only one instance of a function runs even when there are
>   multiple instances of the host web app, you can use the Singleton
>   attribute.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Does this whole thing stands true for topic/subscribe model as well ? So if we have multiple instance subscribed to same subscription the message will be processed by any of the instances  only once?

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for,

Comment: @ImranArshad : That is correct. Unless the lock duration of the message expires before the processing of the message is completed.  When this happens the message will go back to the queue and may get picked again. https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/legacy/message-lock-renewal#:~:text=Default%20lock%20duration%20for%20the,maximum%20allowed%20time%20for%20LockDuration%20.